# Model vs Hash-like Structure for Static Categorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a rather small (~3-10) and static set of categories. What are the trade-offs between creating a dedicated `Category` model or using a hash-like structure? For example...

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Using a Category model
  belongs_to :category
  default_scope :include => :category

  # Using a hash-like structure
  CATEGORIES = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
  def category
    CATEGORIES[category_id]
  end
  # validate_inclusion_of :category_id as appropriate
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benefits of a categories table:

1. foreign keys (if you use them)

Benefits of just storing the "category" as a string and not having another database table

1. everything else